# Assign Task (Journey Builder activity) to contact lead/owner

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, tasks

According to documentation, I should be able to assign a new task to the contact/lead owner in Sales Cloud (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_task_activity.htm&type=5):

> Automatically assign tasks to the contact or lead owner, Salesforce System user, or a custom-defined user

No matter if I try to configure it through the Task Activity or Object Activity, I only have the option to either hard-code the user name of user who will receive the task, or to assign to System User, which is my MC Connect API user.

[image]

Any clue why the option to assign to contact/lead owner is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution:
One must include the contact/lead owner ID in the Journey Entry Data. Once it's there, it can be later selected when defining the task owner:

[image]

Comment: I added it to the Journey Entry Data and I did not get the third option, but the new field was available via the first option. Selecting the field from a drill-down in Journey Data gives you something like: {{Event."DEAudience-b883fc10-d34c-fc87-0d45-f3dae3934656"."ContactOwnerId"}} Maybe this has changed in newer versions of MC.

Answer (score 3):

The only approach that I see currently is to add an Object activity talking to the User Object before the "Task" Event. 
This Object activity you can use to "find and update" the relevant User - which in your case would be the Lead / Contact owner - with *something* - like a timestamp in a custom field.

Once you have such an explicit reference to the User in your journey before the task, another option to retrieve the User appears in the screen you showed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how your solution would have worked, but it gave me an idea - I was not including the contact/lead owner info in my entry data - once included, I have the option to choose it, will post an update below. thanks!!

Comment: Oh I see, you didn't have that. :) 
Great. The point is you need some reference to the User object before the Task event.
This is a common topic in Journey Builder:  the UI sometimes gives you more options on subsequent events, once you have more context established.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know :)